WARNING: Too many active WebGL contexts. Oldest context will be lost (Mapbox+React+Marzipano)
We are using marzipano with Mapbox in one of our project, there we use to display points on map and on click of any point we are displaying 360 images with the help of marzipano.we need to click on multiple points for the images but after 10-15 click, my complete map is getting white (nothing is showing in the screen).
these kind of waring and error we are getting:
WebGL: INVALID_OPERATION: deleteVertexArrayOES: object does not belong to this contextUnderstand this warning
WebGL: INVALID_OPERATION: bindBuffer: object does not belong to this contextUnderstand this warning
WebGL: INVALID_OPERATION: bindTexture: object does not belong to this contextUnderstand this warning
[.WebGL-00001E3C02020D00] GL_INVALID_OPERATION: Must have element array buffer bound.

also there are some steps i followed to destroy the viewer, so that i can get destroy the WEB-GL which is used by the marzipano viewer,
here is the code for it:
async destroyViewerInstance() {
     if (viewer) {
          await viewer.destroyScene(scene);
          await viewer.destroy();
     }
}


I tried destroying the web-gl by using these code
async destroyViewerInstance() {
    if (viewer) {
       await viewer.destroyScene(scene);
       await viewer.destroy();
    }
 }


but the viewer is not destroying and taking too much RAM.

I faced exactly the same problem, I am of course working on Angular, but the following helped me


    ngOnDestroy() {
        if (this.viewer) {
            this.viewer.destroyAllScenes();
            this.viewer.destroy();
        }
    }



